# MySQL - Compare 2 records on the same table

Tags: mysql

I have a user table that has multiple records for each user based on each year..

```
ID | Name  | MemberID
1  | Dave  | qwe/2022
2  | Sue   | asd/2022
2  | Jas   | zxc/2022
3  | Dave  | qwe/2023
4  | Jas   | zxc/2023
5  | Jas   | zxc/2024
```

I am trying to find the users that were here last year but haven't registered this year.

E.g., I am expecting to see just Dave as he was here last year but not yet this year.

I have been working on...

```
SELECT A1.ID, A1.Name, A1.Year, B1.Year FROM `users` A1 
INNER JOIN `users` B1 ON A1.ID = B1.ID
WHERE
A1.Name LIKE = "%/2023" AND B1.Name NOT LIKE "%/2024"
```

I have been looking at this for so long, I can't see the problem.

Comment: You should really consider putting that `year` into a separate column.

Comment: A robust solution wouldn't be based on name..but I guess this is a homework question so not that important,

Comment: are you looking for a record for the last year with a matching name or a matching prefix to the memberID or both?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM
Users U
WHERE MemberId LIKE '%/2023' 
AND NOT EXISTS 
(SELECT 1 FROM Users N WHERE U.Name = N.Name AND N.MemberId LIKE '%/2024')
```

Note that I haven't tried running it. The idea is to get records which are present in 2023 but the same user doesn't exist in 2024, assuming name is unique.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you change to using a LEFT JOIN if you want to look for a missing record

```sql
SELECT A1.ID, A1.Name, A1.Year, B1.Year
FROM `users` A1 
LEFT JOIN `users` B1 ON
    A1.Name = B1.Name
    AND B1.MemberID LIKE "%/2024"
WHERE A1.MemberID LIKE "%/2023"
AND B1.ID IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A1.ID, A1.Name, A1.Year, B1.Year 
FROM `users` A1 
LEFT JOIN `users` B1 ON A1.ID = B1.ID
WHERE right(A1.Name, 4) = "2023" 
  AND right(B1.Name, 4) = "2024"
  AND B1.ID is NULL
```

Using `Right()` generally has better performance than `LIKE`

Comment: I suggest you change the join condition to be on `Name`, and the where clauses to be on `MemberID`

Comment: thanks for the comment. Please note that my code example is here only to demonstrate the strategy, without knowing your data I can't write correct code - and for answering your question I believe it's not even needed.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using `group by` and `having` clauses, the condition is that there must be at least one record in 2023 and zero record in 2024 for each Name :

```
select Name  
from mytable
group by Name
having count(case when MemberID LIKE "%/2023" then 1 end) >= 1
       and count(case when MemberID LIKE "%/2024" then 1 end) = 0;
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/k-B73pY8)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Name
FROM table
GROUP BY Name
HAVING MAX(RIGHT(MemberID, 4)) = '2023';
```